# How to program Motor Controller via SPI

Tags: motor, spi, controller, allegro

I am using Allegro A4962. Our college course requires us to use an industrial grade motor controller like this one which must be interfaceable to external power mosfets, have PWM as the only input, and not to be interfaced with a microcontroller.

This chip can do the job, however, when I read the datasheet, it requires me to adjust the status registers and set the OPM bit for standalone mode.

So my question is.

1. Is there a way to enable this without SPI or programming?
2. If SPI is the only way, how do I interface this, what would I need?

For SPI:
there is an STRN SCK SDI SDO pins for that, yet I still am not sure how to interface that and how I could set that one specific bit.

Datasheet:

https://www.allegromicro.com/en/products/motor-drivers/bldc-drivers/a4964

Comment: 1) It doesn't look like it can be done.